# How to publish console app into executable

Tags: visual-studio, console-application

When I publish my console app I get three files:

1. Application Files (Folder)
2. ClickOnce Application
3. setup

There has to be a way that gives me just a .exe that has everything the app needs to run within in.

I'm using Visual Studio 2010, and don't see any obvious options that would allow me to do this.

Note: Using the setup file appears to just make a shortcut to the ClickOnce Application that I already have.

Comment: Please read this link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5h2db54x(v=vs.100).aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Look in the bin directory of the application, it should have published an executable for you.

Comment: The exe still needs any referenced external dlls